# What does this number mean in PGA Tournament scores?

Tags: rules, scoring, golf, pga-tour

Golf newbie here. I'm watching the Valero Texas Open, round 4. It just started, and a player just completed the 1st hole making a Par in this Par-4 hole (thus having made 4 shots so far).

However the scoreboard says he's got a "1" out of 72. What does this "1" mean? Shouldn't it say he's got "4" (as in 4 shots so far)?

I remember round 3 yesterday they all ended with scores of around 65 or so out of the 72 shots total. But also I remember some of them being at the 18th hole with a score of just "17", which was suddenly updated to "65" when the round ended. Is this a delay thing? Does this number mean a different thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1 means they have completed 1 hole. The 17 meant they had completed 17 holes. Once you finish, they show the total score for that round.

[image]

This image illustrates it. The first number is the players total score through that point in the tournament. One player, Sean O’Hair, had completed his round, so it shows his round score. The rest haven’t, so it shows how many holes they have completed.

Comment: Thanks! So, is there any reason why they don't show the number of shots for the current round/the partial round score? Why do they show the holes instead until the round finishes? (Given that you could summarize the total shots up to that point and show it, why isn't that relevant?).

Comment: They will show current round score for individual golfers occasionally when showing that golfer in the screen. 

The summarizing info they show does help you to know overall standings and how much more of a chance someone has to move on the leaderboard. You know O’Hair can’t move up unless people above move down. You know Day has little opportunity to move into #1 with being 4 strokes back and only having 2 holes to play, etc.